# Cannot count number of characters in a docx file generated from a not empty XHTML

Tags: java, jaxb, xhtml, docx, docx4j

I implemented a XHTML converter to DocX using DocX4J. It creates the DocX file without problems.

To finish my task I decided to implement a simple test. The test consists in counting the number os chars in the DocX created and then comparing it with the already known number of characters from the XHTML (see source code below).

The code of my test is based on a sample from DocX4J site but does not work for me. Although I can see that the content of the DocX created by my converter is equal to the content of the XHTML file, my test code always returns zero to the number of chars of the DocX file. :-\

Does anyone can help me to discover the cause of this unexpected result ?

Thanks in advance!

```js
package main;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringWriter;

import org.docx4j.TextUtils;
import org.docx4j.jaxb.Context;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.contenttype.ContentType;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.exceptions.Docx4JException;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.WordprocessingMLPackage;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.PartName;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.WordprocessingML.AlternativeFormatInputPart;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.WordprocessingML.MainDocumentPart;
import org.docx4j.relationships.Relationship;
import org.docx4j.wml.CTAltChunk;
import org.docx4j.wml.Document;

/**
 * Count chars from a DocX file generated from a XHTML using Docx4J
 * 
 * @author Cláudio
 */
public class CountChars {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
 String xhtml = "<html><body><table border=\"1\"><tr><td>Propriedade</td><td>Amostra 1</td><td>Amostra 2</td></tr><tr><td>Prop1</td><td>10.0</td><td>111.0</td></tr><tr><td>Prop2</td><td>20.0</td><td>222.0</td></tr></table></body></html>";
 int expectedNChars = 57;

 WordprocessingMLPackage docx = export(xhtml);
 try {
     docx.save(new File("test.docx")); // Proves that docx is
                                // successfully created
 } catch (Docx4JException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
 }

 if (countCharacters(docx) == expectedNChars) {
     System.out.println("Success");
 } else {
     System.out.println("Fail");
 }
    }

    private static WordprocessingMLPackage export(String xhtml) {
 WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = null;
 AlternativeFormatInputPart afiPart = null;
 Relationship altChunkRel = null;

 try {
     wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.createPackage();
     afiPart = new AlternativeFormatInputPart(new PartName("/hw.html"));
 } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
 }

 afiPart.setBinaryData(xhtml.getBytes());
 afiPart.setContentType(new ContentType("text/html"));

 try {
     altChunkRel = wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addTargetPart(
      afiPart);
 } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
 }

 // .. the bit in document body
 CTAltChunk ac = Context.getWmlObjectFactory().createCTAltChunk();
 ac.setId(altChunkRel.getId());
 wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addObject(ac);

 // .. content type
 wordMLPackage.getContentTypeManager().addDefaultContentType("html",
         "text/html");

 return wordMLPackage;
    }

    /**
     * Counts chars (even whitespaces) in a docx.
     * 
     * Referência:
     * http://www.docx4java.org/forums/docx-java-f6/how-to-count-number
     * -of-characters-in-a-docx-file-t767.html
     * 
     * @param docx
     *            Document
     * 
     * @return Number of chars in the document
     */
    private static int countCharacters(WordprocessingMLPackage docx) {
 String strString = null;

 MainDocumentPart documentPart = docx.getMainDocumentPart();
 Document wmlDocument = documentPart.getJaxbElement();

 StringWriter strWriter = null;
 try {
     strWriter = new StringWriter();
     TextUtils.extractText(wmlDocument, strWriter);
     strString = strWriter.toString();
 } catch (Exception e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
 } finally {
     if (strWriter != null) {
  try {
      strWriter.close();
  } catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
     }
 }

 if (strString == null) {
     throw new NullPointerException();
 }

 return strString.length();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding your XHTML as an AlternativeFormatInputPart (AFIP) which generally leaves it up to Word to convert the XHTML to real docx content.

In the meantime, the XHTML content is not in the MainDocumentPart documentPart, its in the AFIP.  So of course counting the words in documentPart won't give you what you are hoping for...

Comment: some doubts:    1. AFIP is a non JAXB part, isn´t it?    2. What´s the recommended way to convert a XHTML to DocX in order to preserve its content styles? In my new implementation the program can counts correctly but when I open the docx created in Word it renders the content a little different.

Answer (score 0):

Using docx4j 2.8.1 the correct implementation of the method export should be the following:

```
private static WordprocessingMLPackage export(String xhtml) {
WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = null;

try {
    wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.createPackage();
    List<Object> content = XHTMLImporter.convert(xhtml, null,
        wordMLPackage);
    wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().getContent().addAll(content);
} catch (Docx4JException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

return wordMLPackage;
}
```